# Pytorch MNIST ResNet50 ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist, resnet

https://colab.research.google.com/github/kjamithash/Pytorch_DeepLearning_Experiments/blob/master/FashionMNIST_ResNet_TransferLearning.ipynb#scrollTo=QrIm8SnsUmaK

When I ran this code, I encountered a problem that:

`ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted']`.

anyone knows?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This notebook uses `inspect` unit to assign proper scorer arguments, and it seems the api has changed since the notebook was published. Specifically at this point:

```
def calculate_metric(metric_fn, true_y, pred_y):
    if "average" in inspect.getfullargspec(metric_fn).args:
    ...
```

`'average'` is not in the `args` list anymore. Using `inspect.getfullargspec(metric_fn).kwonlyargs` instead should fix the issue.